# Segue to a ViewController from a UIButton in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I have a TabViewController that has three Tabs, which lead to a three ViewControllers.

I can segue just fine using the actual tab buttons of the TVC. However, I also want to segue to one of the tabs using a UIButton. I have a button in one ViewController and I want to segue to another, but not using the Tab Button.

I've had a couple of partial successes. By partial I mean the VC appears but the TabBar isn't present!

The code for the view controller where the UIButton is situated is below:

```
import UIKit

class HomeView: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var startBtn: UIButton! //Define the start button as a variable
    @IBOutlet var homeText: UILabel! //Define the text on the home screen

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setBackground(); //Set background image
        setStartBtn();
        setHomeText();
    }

    func setBackground() {

        // Apply the insets…
        let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "Background.png")
        backgroundImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
    }

    func setStartBtn() {
        let startBtnText = NSLocalizedString("Start Test", comment: "")
        startBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.clickStart(_:)), for: .touchUpInside) //Add a target and action of the start buton
        startBtn.setTitle(startBtnText, for: [])
    }

    func setHomeText() {
        let homeTextStr = NSLocalizedString("Home Text", comment: "")
        homeText.text = homeTextStr
    }

    @objc func clickStart(_ sender: UIButton) {

    }
}
```

SOLUTION:

The Click Start function looks like this for what I need (thanks to the accepted answer below).

```
@objc func clickStart(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1 // 1 is the second tab
}
```

This allowed me to move to the second tab bar item from a UIButton within the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to embed each vc in the tab inside a navigationController , then use this to navigate to a nested vc

```
@objc func clickStart(_ sender: UIButton) { 
   let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VCID") // set id for the destination vc
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc,animated:true) 
}
```

And this to navigate to another vc inside the tab

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1 // 1 is the second tab
```

Comment: I found the Editor --> Embed feature so this has been done and it DOES work. However, when the new VC appears the TAB bar still has the original VC highlighted. To expand, the left tab bar button is for the home screen. The VC I'm segueing to is the middle tab button. The VC appears but the tab bar doesn't reflect the change. Any Ideas?

Comment: Do you need to chage the current vc inside the tab programmatically ? if so then use `self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1` no need to push in this case , push is when you need to show another nested vc

Comment: Bingo, that was what I was after! Thanks